# MUI Autocomplete endAdornment blowing away default clearIcon

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using an MUI Autocomplete and have added an endAdornment loader to the Textfield while the options are being fetched (from an external source), however this is overriding  MUI's clearIcon (presumably because it is also an endAdornment). How do ensure that the default clearIcon remains? Here is my code -

```js
<Autocomplete
        style={{ margin: 'auto' }}
        options={itemOptions}
        getOptionLabel={(option: Item) => option? option.name:''}          
        value={selectedItem}
        inputValue={filterInput}
        onInputChange={(e, v) => handleInputChange(v)}
        onChange={(e, val) => {
          if (val) {
            handleItemSelect(val)
          }
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Items"
            variant="outlined"
            style={{ width: '300px' }}
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              endAdornment: (
                <>
                  {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={25} /> : null}
                </>
              ),
            }}
            type="text"
          />
        )}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, just need to add:

```
{params.InputProps.endAdornment}
```

to my `endAdornment` like so:

```js
endAdornment: (
                <>
                  {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={25} /> : null}
                  {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                </>
              ),
```